# access to map drive in SQL Server 2019 Dev with EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script python

Tags: python, sql-server

i try to run

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import os
print (os.listdir(r"<share drive>"))
'
```

got:

> **PermissionError: [WinError 65] Network access is denied:**

i try to run this comment with UNC path and get the same error, i still didn't find any solution...

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See

> By default, external Python and R scripts only have read access
> permission to their working directories. If your Python or R scripts
> need access to any other directory, you need give either Read &
> execute and/or Write permissions to the NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad
> service user account and ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES on this directory.
> Follow the steps below to grant access.
>
> 1. In File Explorer, right click on the folder you want to use as working directory, and select Properties.
> 2. Select Security and click Edit... to change permissions.
> 3. Click Add...
> 4. Make sure the From this location is the local computer name.
> 5. Enter ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES in Enter the object names to select and click Check Names. Click OK.
> 6. Select Read & execute under the Allow column.
> 7. Select Write under the Allow column, if you want to grant write permissions.
> 8. Click OK and OK.

[SQL Server 2019 on Windows: Isolation changes for Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-server-machine-learning-services-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#file-permissions)

Comment: There are other way to do it?

Comment: It's not safe to give this permission